# Multidimensional array entry generator

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm currently teaching myself c# by creating a text based rpg, I've decided to add extra challenge by making the floor map (5x5 rooms) randomly generate each time a floor is generated.
it seems that a dictionary with a key = to the position on the map and a list containing tile details seems to fit best (per my knowledge), there's two ways of proceeding that I can think of :
1) the key of the dictionary is a multidimensional array containing the position information.
2) the key is a number between 1 and 25, and the position information is contained at the beginning of the list.

At this point I'm trying to figure out a way in which I can write the values into either and compare them to the previously generated coordinates. I found vectors but those are sadly c++, I've thought of having a For loop iterate through two lists at the same index point in both within an if statement (In my mind it flops between working and not), some odd array comparisons and other ideas all over.

Mainly I'd like thoughts for someone more intelligent than I, maybe ill be able to figure it out if some possibilities are cleared. or if someone has done something like this if I could study their code that would help also.

The room will be displayed as a block of text and the map will be an array like this

```
    0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Yet another possibility for key is `Tuple<int, int>` i.e. x and y coordinates (e.g. `(2, 3)`); multidimensional array as a key is a ill choice.

Comment: Or a simple struct with two integers.

Comment: How is your 'Room' shown on your screen? Do you show the complete 5x5 room text based on screen like a map? Or do you show each location in the room by title / description ?

Comment: The rooms are displayed in a 5 x 5 grid, it is printed out as follows
00000
00000
00000
00000
00000
The room it's self is a description or an event that takes place, i have no artistic skill so as mentioned, purely text based EDIT: seems comments don't retain format so ill add it into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start simple.

For that size of problem a `List<T>` is perfectly fine, just have an X and a Y on each value in your list.

Going from a `List` to a `Dictionary` is an optimization you can do later, your suggestion of a key 1-25 is fine, you can convert back and forth to X, Y using `%` and `/`.

With the List you can just do `rooms.Where(r => r.X == x && r.Y == y)` to get the room you are looking for.

Personally I would structure your 'world' as a graph instead of a grid: each Room would have a dictionary of string (or an enum, or a class instance) to Room where the string would be the direction you want to move.

```
class Room {
    public Dictionary<string, Room> Neighbors;
    ...

room1.Neighbors.Add("north", room3);
...
```

Now you can have directions like `up` and `down`, `out` or `in`, ...

Comment: Yes, the goal is an RPG, so a graph is probably a better structure. See also Eric Lipperts article series on [graph traversal](http://ericlippert.com/2014/10/30/graph-traversal-part-one/).